# Can multiple logistic regression be performed without a reference/baseline?

Tags: regression, logistic

I was wondering of it's possible to perform a multiple logistic regression without a baseline reference. The analysis I'm dealing with doesn't have a "natural" baseline reference. Thanks in advance

Comment: By baseline, do you mean you have a categorical variable, and for this variable there is no level that corresponds to an reference level?

Comment: Clarification: if your dependent variable is binary (logistic regression), there is no reference. Your results will show how all your independent variables increase/decrease the likelihood of a "1" outcome (however you've coded 1). Are you instead referring to using binary variables as independent variables?

Comment: @ShannonC I am not sure I follow: one can **certainly** estimate a binomial outcome model (e.g. logit, probit, clog-log, robit, etc.) with a reference category (i.e. the category for which the $y$-intercept term gives the prediction for zero values of all predictors in the model). One *can* estimate these models without a (single) constant term, by instead providing $k$ separate indicator variables for $k$ separate categories... in effect each term having it's own $y$-intercept estimated.

Answer (score 5):

I interpret your question as follows: You want to do a multinomial logistic regression, and you don't want to choose a reference category for the dependent/explained/left-hand-side/$y$- variable. In that case the answer is: no, you need a reference category. The problem is that probabilities add to 1. So if you have 3 categories and estimated two of the probabilities, you have estimated all there is to know: the probability of the third category is just one minus the already estimated probabilities.

If you don't want to choose a reference category for a independent/explanatory/right-hand-side/$x$-variable, then you can don't need a reference category, see: http://maartenbuis.nl/publications/ref_cat.html

Comment: You can estimate with no reference category by omitting the model constant term, and instead including indicators for each category of a group: $\text{logit}(y) = \beta_{A}A + \beta_{B}B + \beta_{C}C + \beta_{x_{1}}x_{1} + \dots + \beta_{x_{p}}x_{p}$ for the categories A, B and C. Notice there is no $\beta_{0}$ term.

Comment: @Alexis You are right when the reference category refers to a explainatory/right-hand-side/$x$ variable. However, I interpreted the question by the OP as the reference in the explained/left-hand-side/$y$ variable. I have edited my answer to make this clear.

Comment: Retracted my former comment. I think Maarten just cleared some of the confusion we had between our answers, @Alexis. I had interpreted the question as relating to binary logit outcomes, not multinomial, which wasn't quite making sense and why I asked if they meant to ask about estimating the x variables (i.e., if they had dummy variables) with or without references, not the y variable (which then wouldn't necessarily be a logistic regression). If they're talking multinomial logit, I affirm what Maarten said.

Comment: +1 @MaartenBuis Awesome. I didn't even grok that OP may have been asking about the left hand side. TY!